# Class is not a valid document or mapped super class

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.2, doctrine-mongodb

So I use my fork of CalendarBundle (http://github.com/permanaj/CalendarBundle), I install it, configure it, and extend it, because it usually the way to use a bundle. But when I try to run command it return error:

```
  [Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\MappingException]                              
  Class Rizza\CalendarBundle\Document\Event is not a valid document or mapped  
   super class.
```

I already create a Document that extends the parent CalendarBundle Document, but it still return the same error. Should the parent document also use @MongoDB annotation? or just the child document? How to fix this problem?